# Migrating Multisite setup to a different domain

Tags: multisite, migration

I have migrated my wordpress(with network sites enabled) to another domain, changed domain in wp-config.php and change the domain column for the only blog in wp_blogs table in db to the new domain. Problem is i don't see Network Menu anymore when i click my username.

If i delete everything else besides:
`define('WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true);`
and click on network setup, it says that the network is already setup, still i repaste the shown instructions in wp-config.php[after deleting previous] and .htaccess, but no use.

PS:
I also changed my username from "a" to webmaster in db during the process, changed it everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

I would not recommend to change data such as usernames directly in the database, since you might break something....

Having said that I presume you have forgotten to add your new admin username to the site_admins option in your wp_sitemeta database table, therefor you won't see the Network Menu, because your new username is not a site (network) admin.

NB: Keep in mind the site_admins option is a serialized array!